# App crashing while changing reminder alarm in Calendar Event ios

Tags: ios, iphone, calendar, delegates, ekeventstore

In my application I have an option to set reminder for an event. I can add that event in calendar app.After adding event and if I try to change Alarm reminder time to `None`, app is crashing by giving below error.

Terminating app due to uncaught exception:

> `NSInvalidArgumentException`, reason: `Attempt to remove an object that does not belong to this store`.

Can you please help me how to resolve this issue.

[Here is the image for your reference.In calendar event when ever the user select None in alaram settings App is getting crash.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gA1a1.png)

Comment: Hi Thanks for your quick response.But i did not get which code i can add.Because the calendar what i used is a default one.I added image please check once.

Comment: You said that you are setting the remainder for an event and selecting none. Can u post the code of both the actions

Comment: Hi Mr Balaji i edited the question please check once. I dont have any method for for select cell in tableview to change alaram timming.

Comment: ok. then how will you change the alarm time to none. Can you post Code for none option in the image.

Comment: Hi that only i did not get.I am using default calendar and adding even.I don't have any methods which will get trigger when i select any alaram.When ever i select none app crashing with above error.If select something else first and select none app is working fine without any issues.

Comment: i think the second time you go to your event other is not created. Are you using storyboard if so you can try to remove the scene after the event is over so when you go to your event again it will recreate all the object.